# How to upload file to google cloud storage and set it to public permissions and getting the link back

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am uploading files to google cloud storage, and i want to upload the file with public permissions and also if it possible to get the link back in response.

right now i am am only uploading...

My code

```
require_once  dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('/blabla.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Storage::DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);
$storage = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
$fileTmpName="blabla.jpg";
$file_name = "bodzin";
$obj = new Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
$obj->setName($file_name);
$storage->objects->insert(
"creatives_new",
$obj,
['name' => $file_name, 'data' => file_get_contents($fileTmpName),'uploadType' => 'media']
);
```

Comment: there API docs are quite good

Comment: I know, but i couldn't find that.. :(

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the same challenge.

Answer (score 1):

I found this jewel:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#storage-make-object-public-php

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

/**
* Make an object publically accessible.
*
* @param string $bucketName the name of your Cloud Storage bucket.
* @param string $objectName the name of your Cloud Storage object.
*
* @return void
*/
function make_public($bucketName, $objectName)
{
    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    $object = $bucket->object($objectName);
    $object->update(['acl' => []], ['predefinedAcl' => 'PUBLICREAD']);
    printf('gs://%s/%s is now public' . PHP_EOL, $bucketName, $objectName);
}
```

Also something interesting to notice is that the link seems that will always be
https://storage.googleapis.com//